# link_stat error running "rsync" from java program

Tags: java, linux, process, rsync

I wanted to run `rsync` from a java program. Here is the code:

```
        String cmd = "rsync -auv /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv " + archive.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(cmd);

        // capture stdout and stderr from running bash script
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        String line;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        p.waitFor();
        in.close();
        err.close();
```

However when I run this java program I got the error:

```
rsync -auv /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/dev/foundation/validation/archive
sending incremental file list

sent 18 bytes  received 12 bytes  60.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync: link_stat "/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

When I run that exact command `rsync -auv /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/dev/foundation/validation/archive` directly on the server though, it works just fine.

I don't understand why it does not work with Java.

Comment: Are you sure that /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv exists? >> No such file or directory

Comment: @abkrim, Yes. Like I said this command works in command line on the server

Comment: I teste on my mac os. If quoted "/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv" rsync not work. And rsync show that path it's quoted. Example: rsync -auv "*.xml" ~/borrar/ not work. rsync -auv *.xml ~/borrar/  work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I did some research, I found out that this is caused by "*" in the command. It is a wildcard only recognized by bash, I have to run this command with `bash`. Got it to work with the following:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "rsync -auv /rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/foundation/FoundationMedicine/*.csv " + archive.getAbsolutePath()};
```